# Hiding elements with same class after first one displayed

Tags: css

If I have HTML:

```
<div class="myClass">1</div>
<div class="myClass">2</div>
<div class="myClass">3</div>
```

Can I write a rule in my CSS that says:

```
.myClass {
    /* only display the first instance of the class */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:first-of-type`

```css
.myClass {
    display: none;
}

.myClass:first-of-type {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">1</div>
<div class="myClass">2</div>
<div class="myClass">3</div>
```

This will hide all myClass elements except for the first one in the DOM. I have always felt this makes the most readable sense.

Comment: This isn't correct. The `:nth-of-type` pseudo-selector looks for element-types, not classes. (Yes, I know, I wish there were an `:nth-of-class` pseudo-selector as well...)

Comment: For an example of what I mean, have a look at the following: `<div class="myClass">1</div><span class="myClass">2</span><div class="myClass">3</div><div class="myClass">4</div>` - you'll see that not only is the first `<div>` visible, but the first `<span>` is too. Why? Because they are both `:first-of-type`.

Comment: @Rounin However, for his situation of all the same type.  This does work, and makes the most sense.

Comment: Agreed - it does work in this situation, where all the element types are the same.

Answer (score 6):

Rick Hitchcock is very close.

The correct selector is `~`, as in:

```
.myClass ~ .myClass {
display: none;
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

In CSS:

- the `+` selector indicates an element which is an immediately subsequent sibling.
- the `~` selector indicates an element which is *any* subsequent sibling.

Consequently, with the following markup:

```
<div class="myContainer">
<div class="myClass">1</div>
<img class="myImage" alt="My Image" />
<div class="myClass">2</div>
<div class="myClass">3</div>
</div>
```

If you declare:

```
.myClass + .myClass {
display: none;
}
```

then

```
<div class="myClass">3</div>
```

won't be visible, but

```
<div class="myClass">2</div>
```

will be visible.

Whereas, if you declare:

```
.myClass ~ .myClass {
display: none;
}
```

then neither

```
<div class="myClass">2</div>
```

nor

```
<div class="myClass">3</div>
```

will be visible.

Answer (score 4):

This will hide all `.myClass` elements that follow another `.myClass` element:

```
.myClass + .myClass {
  display: none;
}
```

It's basically the inverse of "only display the first instance of the class."  In this case, it's "hide all but the first instance of the class."

**Snippet:**

```css
.myClass + .myClass {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">1</div>
<div class="myClass">2</div>
<div class="myClass">3</div>
```

Comment: This is a nice trick, I've never seen it before.  But it doesn't read that well.  If I were to see this without an explanation I would have no idea what it's doing.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup, very good point.  Readability leads to more maintainable code.  However, regular usage of the adjacent sibling selector makes it easily readable, and this is less code to maintain than having two styles for this functionality.